# Overlapping text out of nested parent (div) while keeping transition:hidden;

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

This is my mockup, how I want it to look. Keep in mind that the text is a overlapping over the nested `div .slider` where the `<h1>` is located.

```
<div class="slider" data-pos="0">

        <div class="slider__slides">
            <div class="slider__slide">
                <h1 class="yellow">happy fruit</h1>
                <h2 class="yellow">slide 1</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slider__slide">
                <h1 class="yellow">happy fruit</h1>
                <h2 class="yellow">slide 2</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slider__slide">
                <h1 class="yellow">happy fruit</h1>
                <h2 class="yellow">slide 3</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slider__slide">
                <h1 class="yellow">happy fruit</h1>
                <h2 class="yellow">slide 4</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Don't really mind these, navigation balls-->
        <div class="slider__dots">
            <a class="slider__indicator" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="slider__dot" data-pos="0" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="slider__dot" data-pos="1" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="slider__dot" data-pos="2" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="slider__dot" data-pos="3" href="#"></a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Here is the mockup.
[image: The Mockup, how I want to it be]

```
.slider { overflow: hidden; }
```

Gives me this result
[image]

```
.slider { overflow: visible; }
```

Gives me this result
[image]

**Conclusion**: I need to have `overflow: hidden;` otherwise the slides will also show and that's not really how a slider should look/work. But then the text will not overlay the top with `overflow: hidden;`

`overflow:visible;` shows the text overlaying but then I get to see the slides left (and right).

Any idea how I can tackle this problem while keeping the  tags nested inside the `.slider` ? I've tried with `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` but neither of those seem to work (bug?)

I've uploaded a [live version here](http://lucasdebelder.be/test/) on my hosting incase you want to play/try something. I can upload it to a jsfiddle if needed as well although it's a ton of code. (If the text is strike-through that means you are viewing it on a bad viewport, try dragging your window down it's only now written for phone/tablet size.)

Comment: Put margin-top on your slides and add position relative and a negative top to your title.

Comment: @NickDeJaeger The text still dissapears in the div (under it)